# Dynamic Javascript in my .html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm struggling with some Javascript in my first rails application.

Partial: _care_point.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({grid: [50, 20]});
    $( ".node_input").each (function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#<%="node.#{care_point.id}" %>").live('dblclick', function(){
      console.log('moo');
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('.node_input', jQuery(this).parent()).show();
    });
  });
</script>
<div id=<%="care_point.#{care_point.id}" %> class='draggable node_chin'>
  <div id=<%="node.#{care_point.id}" %> class='node'><%= care_point.body %>
  </div>
  <textarea class='node_input'><%= care_point.body %></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the output:

```
    <script> 
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({grid: [50, 20]});
    $( ".node_input").each (function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#node.1").live('dblclick', function(){
      console.log('moo');
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('.node_input', jQuery(this).parent()).show();
    });
  });
</script> 
<div id=care_point.1 class='draggable node_chin'> 
  <div id=node.1 class='node'>Moo foo
  </div> 
  <textarea class='node_input'>Moo foo</textarea> 
</div>
```

I first added the dblclick event listener classbased, but that caused it to be added multiple times. This made me change it to a id based approach, but now it does not work. Is it because I try to dynamically build up the id?

Is this even the righ place to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Can you print what is outputted to the browser (use 'view source' on any browser)  to see what has been put in place of variables?

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti - I've updated my post

Comment: It's considered bad practice to dynamically generate javascript. Use static packaged javascript files.

Comment: @Raynos - I don't even know what that means. Could you explain it in a post?

Comment: Views should contain HTML not javascript. Include your javascript in your layout view / master page.

Comment: @Raynos - I need more detail. I thought a partial was a part of a layout? What is the difference between a view and a layout?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I don't know the correct RoR terminilogy. I'm suggesting you put a link to one large bundled/packaged (use the closure compiler for that) javascript file in your "master" / "global" layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 $("#'#node.2'").live('dblclick', function(){
```

To work it must be:

```
 $('#node.2').live('dblclick', function(){
```

i'm no expert of ruby but you must change something here:

```
 $(<%="'#node.#{care_point.id}'" %>).dblclick(function(){
```

I'd try (but i'm guessing - edited)

```
$('#<%=node.#{care_point.id} %>').dblclick(function(){
```

EDIT - Try removing the dots in the ids of th HTML: look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JeHuD/

replace

```
#<%=node.#{care_point.id} %>
```

with (both in the jquery selector and in the HTML (also consider that your id in the html should have double quotes like this: id="node1")

```
#<%=node#{care_point.id} %>
```

FINAL EDIT - in the jquery selector you [must](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) escape dots withdoubole backslashes: here is the updated fiddle that works with the dot http://jsfiddle.net/JeHuD/1/

Comment: Thank you Nicola, but the event is still not triggered

Comment: the problem is in the html i think try removing the dots in th id and it should work

Comment: That was it, thank you so much. I guess the dot is in illegal character in an id?

Comment: No it's not. I checked and the problem is in jquery: if there is a dot you must escape it

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$("#<%="node.#{care_point.id}" %>").live('dblclick', function(){
      console.log('moo');
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('.node_input', jQuery(this).parent()).show();
    });
```

Comment: +1.  @willcodejavaforfood, you've got your quotes in the wrong place.

Comment: Still does not work, maybe Raynos has a point. This is the wrong place for Javascript. It worked until I made it dynamic.

Comment: Raynos point is valid but should'nt really stop your code working. After making the above change can you show me the source/html being generated using the same 'View Source'. It should render > `$('#node.2').live('dblclick', function(){` as Nicola mentioned.

Comment: I've updated my post with your latest code and the new output

Comment: shux. pretty dumb of me. you can't use `.` in your html id. In jQuery selectors, dot notation specifies class. So basically when we ask jQuery to find `'#node.2'`, it goes and find div with the id `id=node` and with class `class=2`. You can replace the dot with lets say underscore `$("#<%="node_#{care_point.id}" %>")`

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were almost there :)